# ggplot embedded fonts in pdf

Tags: r, pdf, fonts, ggplot2

I have been using the following guide to export plots made with `ggplot`to pdf: [plot fonts guide](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/07/30/tired-of-using-helvetica-in-your-r-graphics-heres-how-to-use-the-fonts-you-like-2/.)

It raises the issue at the bottom of the post of some fonts not appearing as they should, which happens in my example below. The text in font Bauhaus 93 appears correctly whilst the text in Calibri is displayed incorrectly.

Has anyone found a way to resolve this issue?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(extrafont)

data1<-as.data.frame(1:5)
data1[,2]<-as.data.frame(c(1,3,5,7,9))
data1[,3]<-as.data.frame(c(2,4,6,8,10))
colnames(data1)<-c("x","y1","y2")

ggplot(data1, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, colour = "Taux selon DEF"), size=0.61, colour="black") +  
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, colour = "Taux selon EC"), size=0.61, colour="black", linetype="dashed") + 
  xlab("X axis lab") + ylab("Y axis lab)") +
  annotate("text", x=1, y=4, label="Some text here", size=2, family="Bauhaus 93") +
  annotate("text", x=4, y=1, label="More text here", size=2, family="Calibri") +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
                     legend.key = element_rect(fill=NA),
                     panel.border = element_blank(), 
                     axis.line = element_line(colour="black", size=0.25),
                     axis.ticks = element_line(size=0.25),
                     panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80", size=0.25),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey80", size=0.25),
                     axis.text.x = element_text(size=5.5 , lineheight=0.9, hjust=0.5, family="Bauhaus 93"),
                     axis.text.y = element_text(size=5.5 , lineheight=0.9, vjust=0.5, family="Calibri"),
                     axis.title.y = element_text(size=6.1, angle=0, vjust=0.975, face="bold", family="Calibri"),
                     axis.title.x = element_text(size=6.1, angle=0, vjust=-0.20, face="bold", family="Calibri")) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,10)) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  ggsave("Test.pdf", width=7, height=5)
Sys.setenv(R_GSCMD = "C:/Program Files (x86)/PDF24/gs/bin/gswin32.exe")
embed_fonts("Test.pdf")
```

Comment: Initially I had the same error, but now I cannot reproduce it! What does the output of `fonttable()` look like?

Comment: The folowing output is given for the calibri family `65                      Calibri                        Calibri FALSE  FALSE  FALSE         NA
66                      Calibri                   Calibri-Bold  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE         NA
67                      Calibri             Calibri-BoldItalic  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE         NA
68                      Calibri                 Calibri-Italic FALSE   TRUE  FALSE         NA
69             Calibri Light             Calibri-Light FALSE  FALSE  FALSE         NA
70           Calibri Light      Calibri-LightItalic FALSE   TRUE  FALSE         NA`

Comment: OK, I've been able to reproduce the problem on Windows: it produces a load of "font width unknown" warnings and all the Calibri characters are jumbled on top of each other. There are a number of related extrafont issues here: https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues Apart from using a different font, I don't know what to suggest!

Comment: Ok, thanks for your efforts. I'll stick to using another font.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try adding `device=cairo_pdf` to the `ggsave()` call. This *appears* to solve the problem for me. This way, it's no longer necessary to use `embed_fonts()`.

See **mgaudet**'s comment here: https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/8

Comment: I also found that using `device=cairo_pdf` embeds the font, but this results in worse kerning – anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: @user1092247 Perhaps the font you've requested doesn't have kerning support. Remember that kerning is done by the font designer, though some systems ignore this.

Comment: Great answer. I found I had to increase the ``width`` and ``height`` arguments inside ``ggsave`` to get a result similar to what I used to get without ``device=cairo_pdf`` on my system before a clean-update to ``MacOS Sierra``.

Comment: Newer versions of R don't support cairo anymore, which gets you `failed to load cairo DLL`. Any new ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @cw' Try installing the Cairo package and then use `device = CarioPDF` in your `ggsave()` call. On Windows it was straightforward. On Ubuntu it was necessary to install `libharfbuzz-dev` and `libxt-dev` before Cairo would compile.