# R does not show correctly the "NewCenturySchoolbook" font type for PDF output

Tags: r, fonts, ggplot2

Why does `ggplot2` fail to print out correctly to PDF the `NewCenturySchoolbook` font type, although it is one of the default font types given in many R examples online.

It works fine for `png` and `svg` output files.

**EDIT:** related problem and solution [ggplot embedded fonts in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542302/ggplot-embedded-fonts-in-pdf)

Comment: you could try the showtext approach, which converts the fonts to outlines, avoiding any embedding issues

Comment: how do I do that? any pointer please

Comment: i haven't used it much but try https://github.com/yixuan/showtext

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double-check that Latex is installed and that it is the default that is used to generate the pdf, and you can add a package to Latex that includes the font.

http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~mgates3/docs/latex-fonts.pdf

Comment: I doubt it is latex's issue. when I output the file and open with any of the pdf viewers that I have on my machine the font does not appear correctly. So I believe the issue comes from the pdf engine of my Rstudio