# different font when output pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, printing, fonts, ggplot2

I draw my plots using the `Palatino` font in ggplot, and I output them using ggplot's pdf device.

When I open the same file with different pdf readers the font appears differently. Some show it as the original Palatino, some show some different font which I don't recognize. There is also difference  from printer to printer when printing the same pdf file.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, and were you able to find a solution?

I'm afraid at the place where I am going to print my final report I might get a font type not as the original one ,i.e. Palatino.

Comment: I think you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542302/ggplot-embedded-fonts-in-pdf).