# Background and text do not show up properly in PDF output of ggplot scatter-plot?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I have a large dataframe consisting of fires that occurred during different years, I have successfully graphed these in a scatterplot using ggplot 2. The problem is none of my text or theme() specifications show up in the pdf. The R plot looks correct, however, upon export the PDF only contains the points.

Here is a sample of my data:

```r
# variable name df1 changed to name data
data <- data.frame(REP_DATE = c("1988-05-02", "2015-04-18", "1981-06-19", "2009-06-18"),
                      YEAR = c("1988", "2015", "1981", "2009"),
                      CAUSE = c("L", "H", "L", "H"),
                      CALC_HA=c("2350.18324","2350.18324", "1825.316641", "2296.424534"))
```

As well as my original code to create the plot:

```r
#load your packages
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
library(PCICt)
library(lubridate)
library(forcats)
library(ggExtra)

# first we need to make it a PCICt object
#set Rep_date as a date
data$REP_DATE <- as.Date(data$REP_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$YDAY <- anydate(yday(data$REP_DATE))
class(data$YDAY)

#subset just the data with H and L
data_H_L <- data[data$CAUSE=="H" | data$CAUSE=="L",]

p<-ggplot(data_H_L, aes(x = YDAY,                                            #set x and Y Axis
                        y = YEAR, colour=CAUSE, size=CALC_HA)) +             #set the colour and size 
  scale_y_reverse()+                        # reverse Y scale to get the years at the top to bottom order
  guides(size=FALSE)+                                                        #remove size legend 
  geom_point(alpha=0.2) +                                                    #set the transparency 
  #scale_color_brewer(type="qual", palette="Dark2")+                         #change the colours here, Dark2 looks good
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#0195D6", "#E66407"),
                      name  ="Fire Cause",
                      breaks=c("H", "L"),
                      labels=c("Human", "Lightning"))+                       #specify colours using unique colour combo
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",date_labels="%b")+  
  #scale_colour_discrete(values=c("#F93800", "#FFB500"),
  removeGrid(x=TRUE, y=FALSE)+                                               # remove x grid
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),                      #set plot background colour
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="black"))+                        #set panel colour
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(1.75,10))+                                   #set scale for size of circles                                     
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4, alpha=1)))        #set size of circles in legend

pp<-p+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", colour="white", size=10, family="sans"),  #set X axis text
             axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", colour="white", size=10, family="sans"), #set y axis text
             axis.ticks = element_blank(),
             panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linetype="solid",size=1),#set y axis line width
             plot.title = element_text(color="white", size=14, face="bold", hjust=0.5, family="sans"),#set main title
             plot.subtitle = element_text(color="white", size=12, face="bold", hjust=0.5,family="sans"),#set subtitle 
             axis.title.x = element_blank(),                                       #set x axis title details
             axis.title.y = element_blank(),                                       #set y axis title details
             legend.text = element_text(colour="white", size=10, face="bold",family="sans"), #set legend axis title details
             legend.background = element_rect(fill="black", size=1, linetype="solid", colour= "white"), #set legend background
             legend.title = element_text(colour="white", size=12, face="bold",family="sans"),
             legend.title.align = 0.5,                                      #set legend title
             legend.key=element_blank())                              #set legend key to blank to get rid of background around dot
ggsave(pp, filename = "whatever.pdf", device = cairo_pdf, width = 4, height = 3, units = "in") #p changed to pp
```

[Here is an example of what the R plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZI8a.png)

[image]

[Here is an example of what the PDF output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8uaK.png)

[image]

I have tried the suggestions below, but cannot figure out why the text will not show up and neither will the specified black background.

[ggplot embedded fonts in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542302/ggplot-embedded-fonts-in-pdf?rq=1)

Comment: you are saving plot `p` and not plot `pp`

Comment: @Mike sorry, I did originally save plot pp, that is a mistake in my question. Will edit now.

Comment: Try to compile the script with tinytex maybe and not save the plot with `ggsave`. Do this, `install.packages('tinytex', dependencies= T)` then `tinytex::install_tinytex()` then restart Rstudio, and compile/knit  in .pdf.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work! The output still had a white background and no text came up.

Comment: I ran your code and I can produce the black image in the pdf file. I'am running R 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 and just updated all packages. Are you maybe running old versions of packages? I also don't need to specify my `device`. It knows what to use from the filename.

Comment: I am running R 3.6.2 and updated all packages, yet the background is still white. I'm glad to hear its working on someone else's machine.